# 20k records are coming from database select query then in foreach loop its hang

Tags: cakephp

I am facing an issue is, i have to select a record from database with specific condition (where status=0), after that if around 20k rows are coming from select query then i added foreach loop to apply some conditions and on condition true i update the status of every fetched row from 0 to 1 and 1 to 2 and so on...

My problem is when large amount of data is coming from database then this process is hang and service stopped.

Please guide me what else i can do on place of foreach...if..else etc...

Comment: Create Shell Script for background jobs! https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html#

Comment: Thank for reply, but can you please give me single example because i am not familiar with this. Please @Salines

Comment: Idea: Have you considered batch processing? using `limit` to only load say 100 records at a time?

Comment: yes i applied shell_exec(command to update records). but i dont thing so that only doing so foreach loop headache will reduce...

Comment: Also added array_chunk on final array which is storing records from database select query, around 20k records, so i used array_chunk(2000), is it fine? or there should be more better way to do so

Answer (score 0):

```
Use hash insted of foreach

// Common Usage:
$users = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'mark'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'jane'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'sally'],
    ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'jose'],
];
$results = Hash::extract($users, '{n}.id');
// $results equals:
// [1,2,3,4];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, here is my code which process i am using is:
if (count($mediaFilesDetails) > 0) {
foreach(array_chunk($mediaFilesDetails, 1000) as $media) {
                   foreach ($media as $key => $imgDetail) {
                     // Query Part to update some data...
                   }
}
}

will you please elaborate how should i proceed...

Comment: please review above foreach loop and let me know how can i reduce its loading time by applying any method because around 10k data is coming so i created 10 chunks of 1000 chunk.

Comment: I am explaining my task deeply is:
1. I have to fetch columns with status 0 (It may be 0 or around 10k...).
2. On resultant array i applied foreach with array chunk of 1000, after that added another foreach loop to use array with key. as mentioned above comment.